# Capybara post request issue

Tags: rspec, integration-testing, capybara

So I'm building an integration that involves submitting a form on a page. But for some reason the database connection is broken during the post request? Or the server isn't accessing the same database?

What's happening is I get a page for a Community, but then when I submit the form on that page   controller handling the post has no idea about that Community.

I've tried turning off protection_from_forgery already. The connections seem to be same (according to AR:Base.connection).

I'm using the shared connection pool method of integrating capybara + rspec.

(ActiveRecord::Base.shared_connection = ActiveRecord::Base.connection)

I'm using Rails 3.0.11, rspec 2.6.4, capybara (1.0.0), and capybara-webkit (0.8.0).

Answer (score 0):

make sure to set

```
  RSpec.configure do |config|
    config.use_transactional_fixtures = false
  end
```

since Capybara tests goes through a separate database connection.

Comment: I'm actually trying to avoid that by requiring it to go through the same connection.

Comment: ok, is there a way to verify the shared_connection is working? Can you take out the shared_connection and use transactional_fixtures = false just to see if the issue goes away?

Answer (score 0):

Actually there are issues with the shared connection hack. If you use the gem mysql2, for example, you'll start seeing some errors like:

```
Mysql2::Error This connection is still waiting for a result
```

Please use this instead. It was written by Mike Perham, all credits to him.

```
class ActiveRecord::Base
  mattr_accessor :shared_connection
  @@shared_connection = nil

  def self.connection
    @@shared_connection || ConnectionPool::Wrapper.new(:size => 1) { retrieve_connection }
  end
end

ActiveRecord::Base.shared_connection = ActiveRecord::Base.connection
```

You'll need to install gem `connection_pool` too.
This will spare you from many headaches.